# Getting Enum values differently

Tags: java, enums

I recently encountered a code change (and I can't ask the guy who did it). He changed the following:

```
//String bar;
MyEnum foo = MyEnum.valueOf(bar);
```

To:

```
//String bar;
MyEnum foo = MyEnum.valueOf(MyEnum.class, bar);
```

What difference does it make (given that `valueOf()` has not been overridden for `MyEnum`)?

Comment: No difference. It is a silly change to make. He is actually calling `Enum.valueOf(MyEnum.class, bar)` with the wrong class-name at the front; which is the same as calling `MyEnum.valueOf(bar)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second approach is definitely "bad style" - as it calls a **static** method of Enum.class on some other class. Meaning:

```
MyEnum foo = Enum.valueOf(MyEnum.class, bar);
```

would at least be more consistent. And quoting from the javadoc for valueOf():

*Note that for a particular enum type T, the implicitly declared public static T valueOf(String) method on that enum may be used instead of this method to map from a name to the corresponding enum constant. All the constants of an enum type can be obtained by calling the implicit public static T[] values() method of that type.*

So, long story short; there is no valid reason to replace ConcreteEnum.valueOf(String) with ConcreteEnum.valueOf(Class, String). To the contrary.